# Frobenius morphism not isomorphism of varieties

Tags: algebraic-geometry

Let $k$ be a field of characteristic $p>0$ and $\phi:\mathbb{A}^1\to\mathbb{A}^1$ be the Frobenius morphism $\phi(x)=x^p$.

According to Hartshorne exercise I.3.2, $\phi$ is not an isomorphism of varieties. Why is this?

I think $\phi$ is the identity map (by Fermat's little theorem), so $\phi$ is its own inverse morphism. Thus $\phi$ is an isomorphism of varieties. Where is my error?

Comment: I think the reason is that the inverse of $\phi$, that map $x$ to $\sqrt[p]{x}$, is not a morphism of varieties. Also, $\phi$ is only the identity on $\mathbb{F}_p$. I guess $k$ is an algebraically closed field of characteristic $p$.

Comment: A morphism $\phi:X\to Y$ of affine varieties induces a morphism $\phi^*:\Gamma(Y)\to\Gamma(X)$ of rings. $\phi$ is an isomorphism if and only if $\phi^*$ is an isomorphism of rings. In the above situation, it is not.

Comment: @Mohan That seems like it would make for a good answer.

Comment: $\phi$ is the identity map on the "$\mathbb{F}_p$ rational points," $0, 1, ... , p-1$.   But there are the only elements of $k$ which satisfy $x^p = x$.

Comment: @Mohan Can you please explain why it's not an isomorphism of rings?

Comment: @BKFH The map $k[x]\to k[x]$ , $x\mapsto x^p$ is not an isomorphism.